# How to define narrow margin in word document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, jsf, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to create a docx document and I want the margin to be set to narrow as if using the Layout > Margins > Narrow in MS Word.

I have seen some other answers suggesting RecordInputStream but I do not know how to integrate it in my code because it uses FileInputStream as a parameter.

I use a ByteArrayOutputStream because I am exporting it with omnifaces and I would like a way to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph titleParagraph = document.createParagraph();
//some code here...
document.write(output);
document.close();    
Faces.sendFile(output.toByteArray(), wordFilename, true);
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing for setting page margins in [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) until now. So we needs using the low level beans `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr` and `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar`.

What `word`calls narrow margins is 0.5 inches margins all around.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordPageMargins {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Text");

  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
  if (pageMar == null) pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setGutter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPageMargins.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Paris Karagiannopoulos: As you see, the code in my answer is minimal, complete and verifiable. If we wants discussing problems, we always needs this, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So please ask a new question about your problem with tables and page margins and do providing minimal, complete and verifiable code which shows that problem. Then for sure you will get an answer. Else not.